# Proper migration path to add a unique token column in existing entity for symfony2/doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to add a new unique token column to an existing customer entity.

I know I need to change the customer class, update the schema, create unique token for each customer.

This is easy in dev as I just wipe the data from the database and start new. But I can't do this on the production database.

So, What is the proper or appropriate method to make this change?

Here are my changes to Customer.php:

```
/**
 * Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CustomerRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("urlToken")
 */
class Customer
{

...

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="urlToken", type="string", unique=true)
 */
private $urlToken;
```

Comment: You are asking how to proceed in a production environment, but at end you can modify the production database, right?

Comment: Yes, I can change the production database. I just want to do it after I am done development and be quick & clean about it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to deploy schema changes on production is to use [Doctrine Migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html).

1) Modify the entity class

2) Generate doctrine migrations:

```
$ ./doctrine migrations:diff
```

3) Update doctrine proxy classes if necessary:

```
$ ./doctrine orm:generate:proxies
```

4) Execute migrations on production:

```
$ ./doctrine migrations:migrate
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the uniqueness of the column.  How do you create a unique column, with unique data in a migration, with all the unique restrrictions?

Comment: So, when you execute migrations:diff, a new migration class will be created for updating the database schema. You can extend or modify the migration class as you need. Also, you can take a look at: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint

Comment: The default migration did not work because the values in the column were not unique.  But I added $this->addSql('UPDATE customer SET urlToken = uuid()'); and that created unique values before the unique index was created.  Thank You.

Comment: Also, for those who are using Symfony2, use the [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)